# workflowservices.js Error (get_context) when attempting to start 2013 Workflow via JavaScript

Tags: 2013, workflow, core-api

I'm attempting to run the code provided in this thread:
[Launch SharePoint 2013 Workflow w/Javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89312/launch-sharepoint-2013-workflow-w-javascript)

It's a function which starts a SP 2013 Workflow given input parameters of Item ID and Subscription ID.

I keep getting an error on this line:

```
var subscription = wfManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription(subscriptionId);
```

I keep getting a TypeError error:

> this.get_context is not a function

Any ideas?

I'm attempting to run this from a web part. I see that `sp.js`, `sp.core.js`, and `sp.runtime.js` all appear to load by default.

The only one which I had to load with a script tag is `sp.workflowservices.js`.

My `startWorkflow()` function runs upon clicking a link, so I don't think it's a matter of code executing before scripts are properly loaded.

Comment: Are you loading the sp.js, sp.core.js, and sp.runtime.js before you are calling get_context() function? Maybe you need to use: 
 SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded

Answer (score 0):

Probably you pass `SP.AppContextSite` instead of `SP.ClientContext` when create `SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager` object.

Below is demonstrated how to properly instantiate `WorkflowServicesManager` object:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var workflowServicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(clientContext, clientContext.get_web());
```

Comment: Hmm...I checked over my code and that's exactly what I'm doing. Thank you for the advice though.