# Designer workflow through Jquery in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, jquery, designer-workflow

Can we trigger a designer workflow on item added event in sharepoint using jquery or SPWEBSERVICES. We have migrated from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint 2013. In sharepoint 2010 we have a designer workflow where in it is attached to a Shared Documents  library. On item added we are moving the file to Drop of library.

Now in 2013 the Document library is named as Documents instead of Shared document library and the workflow is not triggered on item added.

So basically i am looking for a jquery to trigger a workflow on item added.

Comment: can't get how jquery trigger???!!!! will help you. try designing workflow again and attach to the Documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just re-opening the working in SharePoint Designer and re-publishing it?

SharePoint 2013 supports starting a workflow from CSOM, however those are 2013 workflows.  If you wanted to do that, you need to create a 2013 workflow that will call your 2010 workflow using the interop activities.

Look at this SPSO question here on the syntax for starting the workflow:

[Launch SharePoint 2013 Workflow w/Javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89312/launch-sharepoint-2013-workflow-w-javascript)

Comment: Note that you need SharePoint Enterprise to use WorkflowServicesManager